# Key Extraction via electrical signal processing

Tags: key-management, cryptanalysis

Looking for a link to what I believe was recent research that was similar to "[RSA Key Extraction via Low-Bandwidth Acoustic Cryptanalysis](http://www.tau.ac.il/~tromer/acoustic/)" - but instead of being based on acoustic emanations, the research used electrical signal processing. Physical access to the system was required.

Comment: http://www.tau.ac.il/~tromer/handsoff/ ?

Comment: @David: Yes, that's correct, please post your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: **RELATED-QUESTION:** [RSA key recovery using sound - How does it work?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47334/rsa-key-recovery-using-sound-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Get Your Hands Off My Laptop:
Physical Side-Channel Key-Extraction Attacks On PCs](http://www.tau.ac.il/~tromer/handsoff/)